# Can not see resource-id attribute in appium with jetpack compose

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

My android application is built using `jetpack compose`.
Some elements have applied `resource-id` attributes for elements.
But when analyse DOM model on local physical device via Appium Inspector, I can not see that attributes.
And when use BrowserStack, I can see `resource-id` attributes using Appium Inspector remotely connected to BrowserStack.
When desired capabilities or something else I should apply to may see attributes on local device?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Had to add next property for desired capability

```
des_cap['espressoBuildConfig'] = {
    "additionalAndroidTestDependencies": [
        "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0",
        "androidx.activity:activity:1.3.1",
        "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0"
        ]
    }
```